# Postgres: Include Subselect and Derived Calculation from Subselect in the Same Column String

Tags: postgresql

In Postgres I have the following query. There is a column being returned from a sub-select called `filled_out`. I need to include in the same column string, preferably *without repeating the whole sub-select*, the **% percentage** of `filled_out` / `recalls`, the column just before it. Example output is below. Is there a quick way to get this?

```
select s.name, s.description, s.abbreviation, s.created_by, to_char(s.created_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 
count(r.id) as recalls, 
(select count(r2.id) from recalls_t r2 where 
  r2.last_changed_by <> 'ACT24_JOB' and r2.activities_duration_min >= 720 and 
  r2.user_id in (select user_id from study_participants_t sp2 where sp2.study_id = s.id)) 
 as filled_out 
from study_t s, study_participants_t sp, recalls_t r
where ...
```

[image]

Comment: `from study_t s, study_participants_t sp, recalls_t r
where ...` Everybody **loves** the ellipses. Nobody loves the commas.

Comment: The where clause is not relevant to the question, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: You are missing something: respect for the readers.